# How to get back Applications menu?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, appmenu

I'm using 12.04, classic desktop without effects. Once the `indicator-applet-complete` (right part of the top panel) had disappeared. I found how to fix it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Win</kbd>-RightMouseClick on the panel, then "**Add to the Panel**", where choose "**Indicator Applet Complete**" to add.

Now, the left part of the top panel (Applications Menu) has disappeared! If I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Win</kbd>-RightMouseClick on the panel, I can add only individual menu sections like Internet, Office, Settings etc.

How to get back the full menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is: add to the panel the **Menu Bar** option!

Comment: +1, Always good to [ask & answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 0):

If You want to have this in 12.04 LTS unity desktop, You could add the "classicmenu-indicator", which helped me getting the classic menu back into unity.