# I can't see applications under file

Tags: software-installation, launcher, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get back Applications menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194205/how-to-get-back-applications-menu)

In top left in file menu there suppose to be application but it's not there,everytime i have use dash to use my installed programs.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Screenshot will be nice. It help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't have an "Application" menu in the top left, and the menu you're seeing is for the desktop. It should say "Ubuntu Desktop" when you're not hovering over that bar. Application menus in Unity are merged in with the panel, and it will always show the currently focused application.

If you're wanting the "Application" menu, you would need to use GNOME2. You can use GNOME2 by selecting it on your login page. It should be listed as "GNOME (Classic)".

[image: LightDM Screenshot]

If it's not located in the above box, run `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`, logout, and try again.

If you want to stick with GNOME3, you can take a try at Cinnamon. You can install Cinnamon with:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Comment: there is no gnome on the login page.

Comment: Answer updated with screenshot and installation instructions.

Comment: Yes it's working but the bottom taskbar is really small can that go bigger in height.

Comment: If this solved your current question, you should mark it as the answer for future users. The solution for the smaller bar can be found [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40415/how-do-i-resize-gnome-shell-top-bar).